# What is the most efficiant way to deploy Nextjs App that uses prisma(mysql)?

Tags: node.js, next.js, deployment, cpanel, prisma

I've built a Nextjs App as usual, but this time the idea is validated. But after completing development on local and everything is working fine on my local machine, I failed deploying it.

What is the best way to deploy it, with reasonable prices?

I have a shared hosting, and tried so many times to do so on cpanel, but no positive results.

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is off-topic here

Answer (score 0):

[Vercel](https://vercel.com/) is the recommended hosting platform for next.js applications, offering a seamless deployment experience. You can have your app running in less than 15mins.